# Query all objects belonging to user

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have the following two models (only included their relationship to each other). This is a job board site, a business owner can create one or more `Business` objects (on the off chance they own more than one small business) and then post as many `Job` objects as they please.

```
class Business(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
class Job(models.Model):
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
```

How can I get all `Job` objects belonging to a `User`? I know I can get all `Job` objects belonging to a `Business` but a user can create multiple businesses.

I know I have to build some kind of chain filter, I am just not sure how to go about that.

Edit: I am trying to achieve this so I can display all of a user's posts in a dashboard type of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```py
Job.objects.filter(business__user=user)
```

Note the double underscore after "business". That's how you access the business' attributes

Comment: No problem, you can see more examples here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/